# Probability of Diversity Lottery win

Tags: probability

I have entered USA diversity lottery for USA green card. For the region where I have applied from US gov website states applicants have a 1/10 chance of success.

If I apply for 10 years in a row does it become more likely that I will become successful?

I understand that each year is a separate event with a 1/10 chance of success but feel like every time I apply the chances of never being successful must reduce?? sorry for my ignorance, Im sure people are going to say it is still a 1/10 chance.

Answer (score 2):

Your probability of winning in *that particular year* remains $1/10$. However, your chances of winning *in some year* go up the more you play. To see this, if we assume that the draws are independent of each other, you have a $9/10$ chance of losing in a given year, so you have a $(9/10)^n$ chance of losing in $n$ years consecutively, which gets small as $n$ increases.